# how to write circle to ppm file by c++

Tags: c++, image, drawing, geometry, ppm

I want to draw a circle and X into a ppm file.
I use the following method (described below) but I want to know if there is a faster or more efficient method than the method I use.

My method is to create an array of (n X m) size that contains in each RGB struct cell

the array is

```
RGB image[dimx*dimy];
```

the struct is

```
struct RGB {
      uint8_t red, green, blue;
 public:
      RGB() {}
      RGB(uint8_t red, uint8_t green, uint8_t blue): red(red), green(green), blue(blue) {}
};
```

And I write the appropriate values in the right places to get a circle by

```
image[x].red = 0;
image[x].green = 0;
image[x].blue = 0;
```

In the end, I write the array into a ppm file by

```
imageFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&image), 3*dimx*dimy);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create an array of line pointers

```cpp
RGB *pyx[dimy];
for (int y=0;y<dimy;y++) pyx[y]=image+(y*dimx);
```

So now you can R/W access any pixel(x,y) like:

```
pyx[y][x]=...;
...=pyx[y][x];
```

without the need of recomputing address which is much faster than multiplicate on each pixel access...

Another thing is to use 32 bit per pixel instead of 24. So you could get rid of the struct and use `DWORD` or `uint32_t` instead. That way you can set all the color channels at once using `0x00RRGGBB` or `0x00BBGGRR` pixel format. You can even use the highest 8 bits for alpha channel.

If you still need to access the R,G,B you can use union for that:

```cpp
union RGB
    {
    uint8_t db[4];
    uint32_t dd;
    };
```

The only problem is that if your ppm does not know 32bpp then you would need to convert the image data to 24bpp before saving to file